# Geolocation through a personal OpenVPN

Tags: ip, openvpn, traceroute, geolocation

I set up a VPN using OpenVPN on my private server based in a datacenter in France (Gravelines). Everything works fine, my client IP is modified and appear to be in France :

[Informations provided by IP finding services](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCEac.png)

But when i try to access to my intranet website (which need a french IP address to login) it display me a message that i'm in a wrong location.

In try to do a traceroute from my client to the intranet here is the result:

[Traceroute result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wKec.png)

At steps 1 and 2 i can see that the packet is routed by VPN and my private server gateway.
I can't understand how and why the website can locate me at this point. I can provide you any configuration of my OpenVPN server if needed.

Comment: Known datacenter IPs are easily excluded from geolocation databases. Why not get official VPN access to your company? If you *need* it, you’ll get it.

Comment: That's probably the reason. I will upvote your comment. I can't pretend to have one because i'm only travelling for one week... But it was only for fun and trying to do it by myself.

Answer (score 0):

Try in incognito mode. It could be using other features for geolocation, such as cookies.

Comment: Thanks for reply. No it don't works for me.